# become root when running on specific OS

Tags: ansible

I want Ansible to become root only if it is running on a specific OS, let's say, Ubuntu.

I've tried:

```
become: ansible_os_family == 'Darwin'
become: (ansible_os_family == 'Darwin')
become: {{ ansible_os_family }} == 'Darwin'
become: {{ ansible_os_family == 'Darwin' }}
```

neither of those worked.

Is it even possible? How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible. As a workaround you can:

- duplicate the task and put the condition on the `os_family` in a `when` clause

  ```
  - name: Become need 
    command:
    become: yes
    when: ansible_os_family == 'Darwin'

  - name: No become need
    command:
    when: ansible_os_family != 'Darwin'
  ```
- group your host (also) by os at inventory level and define an `ansible_become` variable for os group:

  ```
  [Darwin]
  server1
  server2
  server3

  [Darwin:vars]
  ansible_become=true
  ```

Comment: Defining variables is probably the easiest way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

According to [#11381](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/11381) this should work. All four of your attempts though are incorrect.

These two simply are strings, not evaluated conditions:

```
become: ansible_os_family == 'Darwin'
become: (ansible_os_family == 'Darwin')
```

While these two should produce a YAML error:

```
become: {{ ansible_os_family }} == 'Darwin'
become: {{ ansible_os_family == 'Darwin' }}
```

Have you tried this?:

```
become: "{{ ansible_os_family == 'Darwin' }}"
```